# Differentiating $ y = e^x \sqrt{x} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to take the derivative of:

$$ y = e^x \sqrt{x} $$

I tried completing this question, and my result was: $$\frac{e^x (2x+1)}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Let $u = e^x$ and $v = x^{1/2}$, I followed through the rule and got my answer, problem is it's wrong.. Can someone please complete this question and show me how it's done? Thanks in advance.

The answer should be in the form:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\square}{\square} + \square $$

Comment: What makes you think your answer is wrong? It's fine, although you might also see $ \frac{e^x(x + 1/2)}{\sqrt{x}}$ (that is, divide $2x+1$ by the $2$ in the denominator).

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question and added a photo of the placeholders i get to fill in my answer, how do I transform my answer to be in the form of the 2 fractions and a value? If that makes sense, I just need to put my answer into that box, thank you!

Comment: $\dfrac{e^x}{2 \sqrt{x}} + e^x \sqrt{x}$

Comment: Thankyou! It finally ticked, I need to work on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do it like this:

$$ y = { e}^x \sqrt{x} = { e}^{\left(x+\frac{1}{2} \ln x\right)} $$
$$ y' = y \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} \left(x+\frac{1}{2} \ln x\right) = y \left(1+\frac{1}{2 x}\right) = e^x \sqrt{x} + \frac{e^x}{2 \sqrt x}  $$

Answer (score 1):

$$
y'=(\sqrt{x})'e^x+\sqrt{x}(e^x)'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}e^x+\sqrt{x}e^x=\frac{e^x}{2\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x}e^x.
$$